# Boolean expression order of evaluation in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Suppose I have the following expression

```
String myString = getStringFromSomeExternalSource();
if (myString != null && myString.trim().length() != 0) {
...
}
```

Eclipse warns me that `myString` might be null in the second phrase of the boolean expression. However, I know some that some compilers will exit the boolean expression entirely if the first condition fails. Is this true with Java? Or is the order of evaluation not guaranteed?

Comment: Which compiler or tool are you using?

Comment: Well, javac (the most common compiler) doesn't warn about nullness.  If "Java warns me that myString might be null", most likely that's a buggy tool.  There is no such thing as "java warns".

Comment: That is valid, @notnoop. I'm using Eclipse. My language was sloppy.

Comment: In Eclipse, I can only reproduce the warning with an || operation or with 'myString == null'.  Are you sure that Eclipse warned against this code snippet?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> However, I know some that some compilers will exit the boolean expression entirely if the first condition fails. Is this true with Java?

Yes, that is known as [Short-Circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).Operators like `&&` and `||` are operators that perform such operations.

> Or is the order of evaluation not guaranteed?

No,the order of evaluation is guaranteed(from left to right)

Answer (score 8):

Java should be evaluating your statements from left to right. It uses a mechanism known as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to prevent the second, third, and nth conditions from being tested if the first is false.

So, if your expression is `myContainer != null && myContainer.Contains(myObject)` and `myContainer` is null, the second condition, `myContainer.Contains(myObject)` will not be evaluated.

**Edit:** As someone else mentioned, Java in particular does have both short-circuit and non-short-circuit operators for boolean conditions. Using `&&` will trigger short-circuit evaluation, and `&` will not.

Comment: Quoting: `To prevent the second, third, and nth conditions from being tested if the first is false`. Actually if the operator is `||` the compiler cannot conclude the overall value from the first alone if the first is false.

Answer (score 2):

James and Ed are correct.  If you come across a case in which you would like all expressions to be evaluated regardless of previous failed conditions, you can use the non-short-circuiting boolean operator `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java practices lazy evaluation of if statements in this way.  if myString==null, the rest of the if statement will not be evaluated