# Java: A negative index and the OR logic operator

Tags: java

In the second if statement when I'm comparing values[i]  and values[secondIdx], why doesn't this cause an error seeing as secondIdx is equal to -1?

```
public static int getSecondMinIndex(int[] values) {
        int secondIdx = -1;
        int minIdx = getMinIndex(values);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (i == minIdx)
                continue;
            if (values[i] < values[secondIdx] || secondIdx == -1)
                secondIdx = i;
        }
        return secondIdx;
}
```

Comment: Swap the conditions `if (values[i] < values[secondIdx] || secondIdx == -1)`. Check `secondIdx == -1` first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boolean expression order of evaluation in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028653/boolean-expression-order-of-evaluation-in-java)

Comment: What is the value of `values`?

Comment: It doesn't cause a compile error, but it **does** cause a `RuntimeException` (`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`)

Answer (score 1):

The only ways this would not throw an error at runtime is if you passed an empty array as a method argument, in which case the `for` loop would not execute. Also, as Bhesh suggests, if the array has one element and the `minIdx` is that first element at index 0, the loop will execute once, enter the first `if` and `continue`. It will stop looping right after that. That would also not cause the exception.

Comment: @BheshGurung What's missing?

Comment: What if the array contains 1 element and the `minIdx` is 0?