# If Condition Checking Prority in Java

Tags: java

What's the checking prority of conditions inside if()?

For example in the below code which variable does the compiler start from to check?

On the other hand, if the b1 is true, do the compiler checks b2 and b3? Or the another one is true, the compiler checks others?

```
if((b1 && b2) || b3);
```

Comment: The variables are tested one after amother, from left to right(except something might get optimized away).

Comment: That's not a valid statement - there are two opening parentheses and three closing ones

Comment: Update condition to be `if((b1 && b2) || b3);` remove the `)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean expression order of evaluation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028653/boolean-expression-order-of-evaluation-in-java)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `if`. It would be exactly the same for `result = ((b1 && b2)) || b3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it by yourself:

```
public class ConditionCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if ((first() && second()) || third()) {
            System.out.println("total true");
        }
    }

    private static boolean first() {
        System.out.println("first");
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean second() {
        System.out.println("second");
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean third() {
        System.out.println("third");
        return false;
    }
}
```

When:

- `first` returns **false**
- `second` returns **false**
- `third` returns **false**

It outputs:

> first third

---

When

- `first` returns **true**
- `second` returns **false**
- `third` returns **false**

It outputs:

> first second third

---

When

- `first` returns **true**
- `second` returns **true**
- `third` returns **false**

It outputs:

> first second total true

---

When:

- `first` returns **false**
- `second` returns **false**
- `third` returns **true**

It outputs:

> first third total true

And so on....

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will check the first expression first `b1 && b2` then `|| b3`

Because you defined `&&` which is **Short-circuits And** will not check `b2` if `b1` is `false`, because whatever the value of `b2` will give `false`

, And will check `b2` if `b1` is `true`

Check the table below:

```
1 AND 1 = 1
0 AND 1 = 0
1 AND 0 = 0
0 AND 0 = 0
```

, So we have output `true` or `false` from the first expression `b1 && b2`

if `true` no need to check the second expression `b3` because of the **Short-circuits OR**

, but if the output `false` will check `b3`

```
1 OR 1 = 1
0 OR 1 = 1
1 OR 0 = 1
0 OR 0 = 0
```

[Short-Circuit Logical Operator](https://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=65)

Answer (score 1):

This is the java operator precedence (Operators at the same level have the same priority).

```
HIGHEST
---------------------------------------------------------------------
++(postfix) | --(postfix)   |       |       |           |           
++(prefix)  | --(prefix)    |   ~   |    !  |+(unary)   | -(unary)  
*           |       /       |   %   |       |           |           
+           |       -       |       |       |           |           
>>          |       >>>     |   <<  |       |           |           
>           |       >=      |   <   |   <=  | instanceof|           
==          |       !=      |       |       |           |           
&           |               |       |       |           |           
^           |               |       |       |           |           
|           |               |       |       |           |           
&&          |               |       |       |           |           
||          |               |       |       |           |           
?:          |               |       |       |           |           
->          |               |       |       |           |           
=           |       op=     |       |       |           |           
---------------------------------------------------------------------
LOWEST
```

Parentheses raise the precedence of the operations that are inside them. And then the expression is evaluated from left to right.

So here are the steps for your case:

```
1. (b1 && b2) (let's say the result is res)
2. res || b3
```

Let's say:

```
I:
b1, b2 and b3 = true
1. (true && true) = true
2. true || true = true
3. if(true)

II:
b1=false, b2=true, b3=true
1. (false && true) = false
2. if(false)
Since this result is false, the evaluation is shortcuited here.

III:
b1=true, b2=true, b3=false
1. (true && true) = true
2. true || false = true
3. if(true)
```

Comment: Source: Java the Complete Reference 11th edition

Answer (score 0):

For &&, compiler goes to both the conditions and for || it doesn't go to the right side if the left is true.

In the given condition, the compiler would have to check b1 and b2, if the result is **true** then it wouldn't go to b3 otherwise it would.